# Which DEM format is efficient .tiff or .hgt

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, srtm, hgt

I know this is a vague question, but I've no expertise in GIS world. I was building this terrain map for a game like simulation project that I'm invested in. Data accuracy is least or no concern, but the quality of the terrain it generated. I'm not storing 27GB of data, instead I'm procedurely generating the height maps, from low quality SRTM30 (couple of GB) as I need them. I use mainly GDAL and interpolation (Kriging), numpy and some Scikit-learn. But I was unable to do this in real time.

Which DEM format is most suitable for GDAL or an expensive loop to work with, to produce close real time result.

Are there other choices?

Comment: There's a bit of a tradeoff between drive access (size) and decompression (CPU Cycles).. GeoTIFF offers a choice compression options and GDAL handles that format well; GeoTIFF supports 'tiled' files which makes for faster reading of geographic area. Uncompressed formats (like HFA = ERDAS Imagine) don't offer much in the way of compression so save some CPU cycles but require more HDD access, compressed formats (like GeoTIFF with Deflate compression) can be read from disc quickly but take a significant time to uncompress - critical if you're rendering at 60fps!!

Comment: Though if you're really interested in efficiency steer well clear of doing this in python, it's an interpretative language so it has **massive overheads** compiling each line on the fly, casting from C->python->C objects. GDAL has a very good C/C++ interface which should speed this process up to the point where you can do your Kriging on the fly!